# Limitation on number of users for Craft Calendar 2.x

Tags: craft3, solspace, plugin-solspacecalendar

We are considering using Solspace Craft Calendar 2.x for our new start up users to use as a rostering tool. Is there any limitation on number of users we can subscribe to use Calendar 2.x? We are hoping to scale up within 12 months to have 1200-1500 users.